Minecraft protocol modifying handshake
Currently working on a project and wondering how I can modify the Minecraft login handshake to change a players IP in the game. Essentially modifying what ip the server thinks the player is joining from? Iv read the protocol wiki and haven’t gotten very far wondering if anyone has experience with this?
Iv tried passing IPS through other means but have resulted to modifying the handshake request as I believe would be a more full proof plan

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You cannot do that in that way. It's necessary to use a proxy and/or a VPN.
It's not possible because if you change the IP of the player, the server will not know where to send the packet when playing. And send to a fake IP, or throw error if the IP isn't valid.
If you want to put your own IP or something else, just create a proxy.
In general, I think your real goal can be handled differently than that, but your question is actually almost impossible.

Currently have a proxy attempting to create a way to pass through ips might have to revisit passing them through the other way as I mentioned, not as easy as it’s been for other projects. Https headers make it easy
